# Execute SQL before each db operation using EF Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I want to execute a sql script before each DB operation using EF Core 3.0.

One way to do the same is by subscribing StateChange event of DB Connection. Is there a better way to achieve the same considering performance implications?

Answer (score 1):

You can override DbContext SaveChanges method:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
        {
           
           this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Your Sql");
           var result = base.SaveChanges();
           return result;
        }
```

Comment: Hey..but this will only work in case of save operations. What about select statements? Say DbContext.Sample.FirstOrDefault(); --> This statement will fire Select qurey in DB but wont trigger my SQL

Comment: For all queries,I think you should use [DbConnectionInterceptor](https://entityframework-extensions.net/connection-interception-in-ef-core)